# htaccess mod_rewrite giving me 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

SO I have this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /core/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^page page/%1/? [L]
```

my url is

```
http://localhost/core/page.php?page=8
```

with the rules applied I'm getting..

```
Not Found
The requested URL /core/page/8/ was not found on this server.
```

This is running on wampserver 2.2

the file structure looks like

```
c:/wamp/www/core
```

the .htaccess is inside the /core/ directory.
What is it that I'm missing.. i've checked my apache.conf file and it looks fine.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. You are trying to rewrite **/core/page/8/** to **/core/page.php?page=8** right? See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got it the wrong way around. When logically thinking of rewriting you don't rewrite *original URL* to *new URL* (for example *page.php?page=8* to *page/8/*) you actually rewrite **page/8/** to **page.php?page=8**. You tell the server how it should interpret the unfamiliar URL.

So if I understood correctly what you want to achieve is:

1. User *visits* **localhost/core/page/8/**
2. User is *served* (under the hood) **localhost/core/page.php?page=8**

I believe the following RewriteRule will do the trick (The query string condition is not necessary):

```
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```